# How to update turtles individually in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am currently trying to update multiple turtles individually in python. In the example shown below I am trying to have the bottom turtle move and based on player input and update constantly while the top turtle move forward and backwards and update based on certain intervals.

```
import turtle
from time import sleep
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Turtle Test")
screen.bgcolor("grey")
screen.setup(width=630, height=630)
screen.tracer(0)

turtle_a = turtle.Turtle()
turtle_a.speed(0)
turtle_a.shape("square")
turtle_a.color("white")
turtle_a.penup()

turtle_b = turtle.Turtle()
turtle_b.speed(0)
turtle_b.shape("square")
turtle_b.color("black")
turtle_b.penup()

turtle_b_speed = 10

def go_left():
    x = turtle_b.xcor()
    x -= turtle_b_speed
    turtle_b.setx(x)

def go_right():
    x = turtle_b.xcor()
    x += turtle_b_speed
    turtle_b.setx(x)

screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(go_left, "Left")
screen.onkeypress(go_right, "Right")

direct = 5

while True:
    turtle_a.goto(turtle_a.xcor() + direct, turtle_a.ycor())
    sleep(0.5)
    if turtle_a.xcor() >= 310:
        direct = -5
    if turtle_a.xcor() <= -310:
        direct = 5
    # update function
```

Comment: So what's going wrong with your code? What do you have working right now?

Comment: I'm trying to have the bottom turtle constantly move because when I insert screen.update() where # update function is, every time right or left is pressed the bottom turtle only moves when the top turtle does.

Comment: this line here:     `if turtle_a.xcor() == 310:
        direct = -5` I assume you are checking if you've reached one extreme of the screen and turning around.  instead of `==` use `>=` so that if your turtle doesn't land exactly in spot 310 he will still turn around. Similairly with `<=` for the next if statement.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed those lines, but do you know anyway to fix the update loop?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am not super familiar with turtle.  Perhaps printing out `turtle_a.xcor()` inside your `while True` loop to make sure it's acting the way you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you've already gone down the wrong road when you import turtle twice, two different ways as well as using `sleep()` in an event-based environment like turtle:

```
import turtle
from time import sleep
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
```

You also shouldn't be using a `while True:` loop in an event-based environment, but rather a timer event.  Below is a rewrite of your code that fixes these issues.  Since you never set a Y coordinate for the two turtles, there is no 'top' nor 'bottom', just two turtles moving past each other:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def go_left():
    x = turtle_b.xcor() - turtle_b_speed

    if -300 <= x <= 300:
        turtle_b.setx(x)

def go_right():
    x = turtle_b.xcor() + turtle_b_speed

    if -300 <= x <= 300:
        turtle_b.setx(x)

def move_a():
    global turtle_a_direct

    turtle_a.setx(turtle_a.xcor() + turtle_a_direct)

    if not -300 <= turtle_a.xcor() <= 300:
        turtle_a.undo()
        turtle_a_direct *= -1

    screen.ontimer(move_a, 500)

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Turtle Test")
screen.bgcolor('grey')
screen.setup(width=640, height=640)

turtle_a = Turtle('square')
turtle_a.speed('fastest')
turtle_a.color('white')
turtle_a.penup()

turtle_a_direct = 5

turtle_b = Turtle('square')
turtle_b.speed(0)
turtle_b.color('black')
turtle_b.penup()

turtle_b_speed = 10

screen.onkeypress(go_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(go_right, 'Right')
screen.listen()

move_a()

screen.mainloop()
```

Since you invoked `onkeypress()`, I'm assuming Python 3.

Comment: I know this is late, but do you have a solution that would work for around 50 turtles?